# How to run powershell script from remote machine with Java?

Tags: java, powershell, windows-server-2012

I have a powershell script on remote machine(call it getMachineDetails.ps1). What I want to do is, run this script on remote machine and get output. I am using Java and I don't know how to connect and run this script on remote machine. Can I use WMI or is there any other java library?

By the way Windows Server 2012 installed on remote machine.